# Could someone help me with this crash report

Tags: android, crash

```
Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/kltevzw/kltevzw:5.0/LRX21T/G900VVRU2BOE1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '14'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 30968, tid: 30968, name: com.myapp >>> com.myapp <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(295)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report
'
r0 00000000 r1 000078f8 r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 b6f5c114 r5 00000006 r6 0000000b r7 0000010c
r8 b6f3be04 r9 bec21408 sl 00000000 fp bec213cc
ip 000078f8 sp bec20ee0 lr b6ee5fd1 pc b6f09970 cpsr 600f0010

backtrace:
#00 pc 00037970 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00013fcd /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
#02 pc 00014beb /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00011531 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
#04 pc 0000fcbc /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 002a7569 /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so
```

I have no clue what this is telling me but I do believe it has something to do with webview given the last line. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue in `jni_android.cc(295)`. I have a `ẀebView` inside a `Fragment`. When quickly opening and closing the Fragment, chromium WebView would cause the whole app to crash. This is what helped:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    webView=null; // remove webView, prevent chromium to crash
}
```

Comment: For completeness, the same issue was witnessed here: https://github.com/laurencedawson/reddit-sync-development/issues/990

Comment: Thanks for the help I will give it a try.

Comment: Did you put this in your MainActivity you're going back to or inside the class where you extend the Fragment class? @sulai

Comment: @Vaia: it's part of the Fragment class, e.g. `WebViewFragment extends Fragment`.

Comment: @sulai what about kotlin?

Comment: @BipinBharti try `var webView: WebView?`, which is basically a nullable variable in kotlin.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue and after hours of trial and error, I have finally solved this. All you have to do is `destroy()` the WebView before Activity finishes

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (myWbView != null)
        myWbView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Maybe `if (myWbView != null)` is not really necessary, but I wrote it anyway to stay safe

Comment: My app only has one activity. So can I conclude that it crashes on exit? A crash at the end, which the user probably doesn't even notice, really doesn't interest me that much. :)

Comment: User might get repeated crash popups "This app has stopped", which, I would say, is pretty annoying