# What is A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(236)]?

Tags: android, webkit, chromium

I am working with WebView and I have managed to show a custom ActionMode menu. Suddenly every time there is a long press on the WebView I get this crash. I can't understand the reason behind mainly because I don't know what this error represents.

```
A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(236)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
```

a full stack trace can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/amrfarid140/4e1c2364cc4d90e4ba28ac964b54bf4c)

any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backtrace is as follows, it's abort at the address of your webview.apk, you may can have a try to use `addr2line` to get the symbol from the address `0x0000000002b5f3c8` of the webview.apk(need full symbol in it) to see where it happended:

```
02-08 16:48:53.575 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-08 16:48:53.575 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:7.1/NPF26K/3479480:userdebug/test-keys'
02-08 16:48:53.575 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
02-08 16:48:53.575 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86_64'
02-08 16:48:53.575 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: pid: 30263, tid: 30263, name: ols.schoolsdemo  >>>com.amr.demo <<<
02-08 16:48:53.575 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
02-08 16:48:53.576 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(236)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
                                          '
02-08 16:48:53.576 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     rax 0000000000000000  rbx 000079fce8a1dbe8  rcx ffffffffffffffff  rdx 0000000000000006
02-08 16:48:53.576 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     rsi 0000000000007637  rdi 0000000000007637
02-08 16:48:53.576 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     r8  0000000000000323  r9  000079fcd4c46f60  r10 0000000000000008  r11 0000000000000202
02-08 16:48:53.576 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     r12 0000000000007637  r13 0000000000000006  r14 000079fce46e8000  r15 00007fff52ffe618
02-08 16:48:53.576 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
02-08 16:48:53.576 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     rip 000079fce4681ba7  rbp 000000000000000b  rsp 00007fff52ffdcb8  eflags 0000000000000202
02-08 16:48:53.577 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
02-08 16:48:53.577 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000008dba7  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+7)
02-08 16:48:53.577 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000008a641  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+65)
02-08 16:48:53.577 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000302c1  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+17)
02-08 16:48:53.577 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000287fd  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+77)
02-08 16:48:53.577 30753-30753/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000002b5f3c8  /system/app/webview/webview.apk (offset 0x3ddb000)
```

Comment: So I am getting something from the wrong address. I am going mark it answered but I would appreciate any clues about what would that item be.

Comment: @amr, you may can have a look and trace the code of src/base/android/jni_android.cc in https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/base/android/jni_android.cc?q=jni_android.cc+package:%5Echromium$&dr, and there is similar issue with you as follows:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416568/could-someone-help-me-with-this-crash-report